# Android RenderScript Matrix_2x2 Element Data Type

Tags: android, matrix, types, element, renderscript

I have a question about MATRIX_2X2 Element in Android RenderScript framework:

```
RenderScript myRS = RenderScript.create(this);
Element myElement = Element.MATRIX_2X2(myRS);
```

I have no idea what are the data types of the entries of this matrix, that is, int16, int32, float32, etc.

In other words, I do not know how to create a MATRIX_2X2 Element with entries of my desired data type.

I could not find any documentation on Android Developers website on this issue, and I would appreciate if someone helps me on this problem.

**EDIT:**

Now that we know the data types are float32, I wrote a simple test code.
This is the kernel code (Test.rs):

```
rs_allocation in;

rs_matrix4x4 __attribute__((kernel)) root(uint32_t x)
{
    rs_matrix4x4* a = (rs_matrix4x4*) rsGetElementAt(in, x);
    rs_matrix4x4 out;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        out.m[i] = a->m[i] + 1;
    return out;
}
```

I intentionally defined 'in' as a global variable.

This is the java test code:

```
float[] in_1d = new float[32];
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    in_1d[i] = (float) i;

RenderScript myRS = RenderScript.create(this);

Allocation inAllocation;
Allocation outAllocation;

Type myType = Type.createX(myRS, Element.MATRIX_4X4(myRS), 2);

inAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(myRS, myType);
outAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(myRS, myType);

inAllocation.copyFromUnchecked(in_1d);

ScriptC_Test myScript = new ScriptC_Test(myRS);

myScript.set_in(inAllocation);

myScript.forEach_root(outAllocation);

float[] out_1d = new float[32];
outAllocation.copyTo(out_1d);

inAllocation.destroy();
outAllocation.destroy();
myType.destroy();
myRS.destroy();
```

But when I run the application, at this line:

```
outAllocation.copyTo(out_1d);
```

this exception is thrown:

```
android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: 32 bit float source does not match allocation type MATRIX_4X4
```

If I use:

```
inAllocation.copyFrom(in_1d);
```

instead of:

```
inAllocation.copyFromUnchecked(in_1d);
```

I would get the same exception for the input allocation. But there is not such 'copyToUnchecked' method in order to be used instead of 'copyTo'.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In API 23 you could use copy1DRangeToUnchecked(), but in earlier versions you probably have to limit the use of MATRIX_4X4 to allocations that you do not need to copy to Java-side memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rs_matrix classes only contain floats. You cannot create them for any other types.